# solve paypal error in woocommerce of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem. Please give some solution of this type of error in wordpress. i have use eduma wordpress theme. and in that courses are there when any course purchase it is process to checkout and end of payment  via paypal give error. please give solution.

Comment: Please show your code, Error logs, What you have tried so far?

Comment: ti is wordpress code not hand made code...

Comment: 1) have you put your credentials correctly?, 2) have checked theme documentation?

Comment: 1) have you put your credentials correctly?, 2) have checked theme documentation?